# How to refactor service methods that just forward request to DAO?

Tags: java, design-patterns, software-design

I have a spring mvc project ,there is quite a lot of code in service layer that just forward request to DAO layer, just as in this example.

https://www.journaldev.com/3531/spring-mvc-hibernate-mysql-integration-crud-example-tutorial

```java
    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void updatePerson(Person p) {
        this.personDAO.updatePerson(p);
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public List<Person> listPersons() {
        return this.personDAO.listPersons();
    }
```

And according to *A Philosophy of Software Design*, it is not good.

So what is a better way to refactor service layer and DAO layer?

Comment: Put the invoke in a `try catch` block and then log if there is any error. By the way, why do you put a `@Transactional` for a read operation?

Comment: There's nothing inherently wrong about calling the DAO directly w/o having to call a service in between - layered architecture always comes with a price and you observed one price on your own.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a bad practice but "separation of concern".

The service layer is the transaction boundary, is responsible for data transformation (object to json for example) and usually also takes care of security.

On the other hand the DAO layer is responsible for data access.

The advantage of separating these two layers is testability. You can test them independently.

Answer (score 0):

@Transactional scope better to be in dao layer only..In service layer you can do pre and post processing and data transformation..